# Word to code using SQL TeraData

Tags: teradata

I have this question and don't know how to write the proper query to run this.

> Ohio has a large number of Dillard’s locations (21 in all). Ohio is also a large and diverse state. Each store naturally does a different volume of business and local customers demand different products.  While this allows local store managers to exercise their judgement about their own clientele, corporate management monitors the financial results at each store.
>
> Initially, the sales manager wants to rank the stores in Ohio from the lowest dollar volume of total sales to the highest during the year 2005. In your query, remember to include only Purchases (stype = ‘P’).

I have this query that I have written but comes up with error 3707 which is Code =

> 3707: Syntax error, expected something like a name or a Unicode
> delimited identifier between the word 'stype' and '='.

What I have written is this

```
SELECT saledate, stype, amt, SUM(amt) AS “Total Dollar Volume” 
FROM trnsact   
WHERE state = 'OH' saledate BETWEEN '20050101AND '20051231'
ORDER by sprice ASC
```

I am using the Teradata which my professor has provided.

Comment: Your query doesn't match the error message. Can you show your actual Select?

Comment: @dnoeth i had stype = 'P', instead of just stype. how would I elaborate the question given to me to a code.

Comment: Where did you have `stype = 'P'`, in the Select list? This should be an `AND`ed WHERE-condition. Additionally you need to use the store_id and GROUP BY it.

Comment: I had it in the same place as the current stype in the post. I am not really familiar with GROUP BY. Is it possible if you could show me what it has no contain.

Comment: If you get a task like this you must know about `GROUP BY` (you use `SUM`, too). `SELECT store_id, SUM(amt) FROM ... WHERE ... GROUP BY store_id ORDER BY ..`

Answer (score 0):

There are many syntax errors and errors on requirements in the query :

- you don't close the literal `20050101`
- you don't put `AND` after `WHERE state = 'OH'`
- there's not space between `20050101` and `AND`
- you don't use the `GROUP BY` which is needed for using group functions as sum.  Moreover having the `amt` and `sum(amt)` listed doesn't make a lot of sense, because grouping for it will list every specific amount of each store. Moreover, as your query looks as a resume of all purchases in the period for each store you don't need  the `saledate` either. So you should remove the `amt` and the `saledate` fields
- you don't put the condition for `stype='P'`, as required
- you don't add the store id to the field list. How can the managers understand which store are we reading the data ?
- the `ORDER BY` should be by `SUM(amt)` .

So your query should became as follows, assuming the transact table has a record for every transation (purchases, etc ) and the store id is in a field called `store_id` (you should change this !).

```
SELECT store_id, SUM(amt) AS "Total Dollar Volume"
FROM trnsact   
WHERE state = 'OH' AND saledate BETWEEN date '2005-01-01' AND date '2006-01-01' - 1 AND  stype='P'
GROUP BY store_id
ORDER by sum(amt) ASC
```

Comment: `saledate BETWEEN date '2005-01-01' AND date '2005-12-31'` (and I would prefer `saledate BETWEEN date '2005-01-01' AND date '2006-01-01' - 1`)

Comment: Looks like you've added the oblique quotes that the OP is using as well - the database is likely going to choke on those.

Comment: @halfer: Which quotes? The query is fine (besides the missing dashes in `date '20050101'`)

Comment: @dnoeth: I would guess `“Total Dollar Volume”` should be `"Total Dollar Volume"`. I don't know this particular SQL engine, but most RDBMS would throw a syntax error.

Comment: @halfer: Now I see, of course that should be straight double quotes, not the typographical curly quotes, probably created by a "smart" editor :-)